# Preferred way of defining properties in Python: property decorator or lambda?

Tags: python, lambda, properties, decorator

Which is the preferred way of defining class properties in Python and why? Is it Ok to use both in one class?

```
@property
def total(self):
    return self.field_1 + self.field_2
```

or

```
total = property(lambda self: self.field_1 + self.field_2)
```

Comment: Where have you seen this "property via lambda" that would cause you to think it could be "preferred"?  Did you see a lot of these?  If so, where?

Comment: @S.Lott Some python book, I don't remember. I will use decorators from now on. No problem. :-)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The decorator form is probably best in the case you've shown, where you want to turn the method into a read-only property.  The second case is better when you want to provide a setter/deleter/docstring as well as the getter or if you want to add a property that has a different name to the method it derives its value from.

Comment: S.Lott - why not? (Not arguing- just curious)

Comment: @S.Lott: ok but what's your workaround to the limitation of lambdas not allowing docstrings though?

Answer (score 51):

For read-only properties I use the decorator, else I usually do something like this:

```
class Bla(object):
    def sneaky():
        def fget(self):
            return self._sneaky
        def fset(self, value):
            self._sneaky = value
        return locals()
    sneaky = property(**sneaky())
```

**update:**

Recent versions of python enhanced the decorator approach:

```
class Bla(object):
    @property
    def elegant(self):
        return self._elegant

    @elegant.setter
    def elegant(self, value):
        self._elegant = value
```

Comment: I'm getting errors when using flake8, pyflakes when using this notation. I get redefinition of function 'elegant' warnings.

Comment: With Pylint, there is an additional benefit to use the decorator. See [Pylint warning `W0212` with properties accessing a protected member: how to avoid?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24833362/pylint-warning-w0212-with-properties-accessing-a-protected-member-how-to-avoi). It preserves Pylint's ability to check the returned value/object.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use lambdas for this. The first is acceptable for a read-only property, the second is used with real methods for more complex cases.