# Pylint w0212-Warning while doing unittests

Tags: python, private, pylint

we often use this double underscore prefix for internal methods of our classes. This usually raises a W0212 during unit-testing, because we call the proctected methods directly e.g. `TestClass().__my_private_method()`.

I know that in Python there are no private methods. Nevertheless I find this practice of using the underscore prefix good for structural reasons, e.g., it makes it quite obvious to other developers how to use a class.

Now I found this fix for the W0212-Warning from the [phoenix-github-page](https://vald-phoenix.github.io/pylint-errors/plerr/errors/classes/W0212.html):

```
class Foo:
    def __bar(self):
        pass

    def baz(self):
        return self.__bar()


foo = Foo()
foo.baz()
```

Based on this you could create a method for unittest without disabling W0212 like this:

```
class SomeClass:
    """ some docstring
    """
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.myattr = 1

    def __my_protected_method(self):
        return self.myattr + 1

    def __another_protected_method(self):
        return self.myattr + 2

    def method_for_unittests(self, method_name):
        if method_name == "my_protected_method":
            return self.__my_protected_method()
        if method_name == "another_protected_method":
            return self.__another_protected_method()
        return None
```

This seems like a nicer solution than using a seperate `.pylintrc` (suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57602259/disable-pylint-protected-access-just-for-unit-tests)). This begs the following questions:

1. Does my solution make sense or should we just stick with `#pylint: disable=protected-access`?
2. Or do you maybe have a better solution using a special decorator? I saw something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24833362/pylint-warning-w0212-with-properties-accessing-a-protected-member-how-to-avoi), which made me curious. I have little experience writing decorators, therefore the comparatively naive question.

Comment: What are you doing in unit testing that's causing the warning?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I updated the question. We usually call the a protected method directly e.g. `TestClass().__my_private_method()`

Comment: Well then there's the problem. Test through the public interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With pylint it's always possible to disable the message, or to make it disappear by using a hack. But it's better to simply disable messages than to hack something that will make pylint stop complaining (but won't make the code better). The best thing to do is to understand the underlying issue to fix it.

If you're creating a function that will be used only for tests (a test only API) you're doing a hack to make pylint think you're using a public API. What you should do instead is to test private/protected methods through the public interface of your function (through the real API used everywhere) as pointed out by @jonrscharpe in comment.

If you can't do that, then it means that a private class is hiding inside your code waiting to be created.

Advertisement: We're trying to include and improve the documentation work of valid-phoenix that you linked in the question into pylint. You can help the pylint team make better suggestions of fixes, see https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/5953

Comment: Thanks I considered making a suggestion. However I felt like I did not understand the issue well enough. In addition I currently have not formed my opinion if I found the phoenix-solution to W0212 useful or misleading. Sometimes the phoenix-site doesn't show an easy fix - that is usually a sign that this pylint message has more than one possible answer