# Decorating a property: right order

Tags: python

Is there a preferred way of decorating a class property?
As I see it you could either decorate the property itself with another property or you could decorate the underlying method and then apply `@property` on that.
Are there any considerations to make for either approach?

```
def decorate_property(prop):
    @property
    def inner(instance):
        return prop.__get__(instance) + 1
    return inner

def decorate_func(func):
    def inner(instance):
        return func(instance) +1
    return inner

class A:

    x = 1

    @decorate_property
    @property
    def f(self):
        return self.x

    @property
    @decorate_func
    def g(self):
        return self.x

a = A()
print(a.f) # 2
print(a.g) # 2
```

Comment: Check this out - https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property

Comment: This too - https://www.codementor.io/sheena/advanced-use-python-decorators-class-function-du107nxsv

Comment: Possible duplicate of - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406567/preferred-way-of-defining-properties-in-python-property-decorator-or-lambda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Properties are objects ([descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors)) that wrap functions. Which one to decorate depends on which one you intend to change.

1. If you want to change what the `property` *does*, decorate the initial function.

   ```
   @property
   @plus_one  # add one to the result of the function
   def a(self):
       return self._a
   ```

   This also applies to changing the `setter` and `deleter`.

   ```
   @property
   @plus_one  # add one to the result of the function
   def a(self):
       return self._a

   @a.setter
   @minus_one  # remove one from the input of the function
   def a(self, value):
       self._a = value
   ```
2. If you want to change what the `property` *is*, decorate the resulting descriptor.

   ```
   @random_repr  # add a new repr to the descriptor
   @property
   def a(self):
       return 1
   ```

   Note that defining `setter` and `deleter` creates a *new* descriptor. You need to decorate the last descriptor created.

   ```
   @property
   def a(self):
       return self._a

   @random_repr  # add a new repr to the final descriptor
   @a.setter
   def a(self, value):
       self._a = value
   ```

---

For the most part, a `property` is used to get a certain behaviour expressed by a function (case 1). The data descriptor (case 2) is an implementation detail that most people are not familiar with. In case of doubt, decorate the function - this case is the more generic and easier to understand.